# Print the index of the array in his toString method

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, tostring

Hi all and sorry for my English, I'm not very good at writing.

I am actually programming a booking system for a cinema (it is an University project). I have a LinkedList of Users and inside i put an ArrayList of booked seat. The bookedSeat Class is the following:

```
public class bookedSeat implements Serializable {

private Hours h;
private Days d;
private int hallNumber;
private int seatNumber;
//getter&setter and constructor below...
```

When i display the booking of a user i use the toString method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    String ret="\n \033[31m Booking "  +  ": day: " + getD() 
    + ", Hall: " + getH() + ", hour: " + getH() + ", seat number: " + 
    getSeatNumber() + "\n";
    return ret;
}
```

I get this output once i book a couple of seat:

```
User{Nome=Daniele, Booked Seat: [
Booking : Day: 24, Hall: 1, hour: 20, seat number: 45
, 
Booking : Day: 29, Hall: 1, hour: 20, seat number: 24
]}
```

I now ask to user which booking he wants to dismiss and i ask him to write the number of booking so i can save this value-1 and remove the related index (1 for the first, 2 for the second etc...).

Is there a chance to get the number of the Booking from the toString method? to be more clear: I want this output from the toString:

```
User{Nome=Daniele, Booked Seat: [
Booking 1: Day: 24, Hall: 1, hour: 20, seat number: 45
, 
Booking 2: Day: 29, Hall: 1, hour: 20, seat number: 24
]}
```

Thanks for any efforts to help!

Comment: Since the Booking class has implemented the `toString` you cannot produce such a result unless you change the Booking's toString result in User class.. Sort of replace `Booking :` with `Booking <index>:`

Comment: If you have the luxury to change Booking's toString, remove the word `Booking`. Then in the User class you can add it along with the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the index to the final string in the `toString` of `User`, not `BookedSeat`.

```
// User.toString
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder("User{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", bookedSeats=[");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bookedSeats.size() ; i++) {
        retVal.append("Booking ");
        retVal.append(i + 1);
        retVal.append(": ")
        retVal.append(bookedSeats.get(i));
        retVal.append("\n");
    }
    retVal.append("]\n}");
    return retVal.toString();

}

// BookedSeat.toString
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hours: " + h +
            ", Days: " + d +
            ", Hall Number: " + hallNumber +
            ", Seat Number: " + seatNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add a counter variable in your `bookedSeat` class to record the number of seats booked and then get it using toString.

In `bookedSeat`:

```
....your code
private int noOfSeatsBooked;
```

In `toString()`

```
String ret="\n \033[31m Booking " + getnoOfSeatsBooked() +  ": day: " + getD() 
+ ", Hall: " + getH() + ", hour: " + getH() + ", seat number: " + 
getSeatNumber() + "\n";
return ret;
}
```

Use a loop to increment the seats booked every time.